# Keep Convolution Neural Networks model

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

How to keep the training result of convolution neural network, so that different data can be used it again for testing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **keras** with tensorflow then you can save the model in **json** and weights in a **hdf5** file format.

```
# keras library import  for Saving and loading model and weights

from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.models import load_model

# serialize model to JSON
#  the keras model which is trained is defined as 'model' in this example
model_json = model.to_json()


with open("model_num.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model_num.h5")
```

files "model_num.h5" and "model_num.json" are created which contain our model and weights

To use the same trained model for further testing you can simply load the hdf5 file and use it for the prediction of different data. 
here's how to load the model from saved files.

```
# load json and create model
json_file = open('model_num.json', 'r')

loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model_num.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

model.save('model_num.hdf5')
loaded_model=load_model('model_num.hdf5')
```

To predict for different data you can use this

```
loaded_model.predict_classes("your_test_data here")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using keras you can save it in the format hdf5 file and load it for testing.

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('path where you want to save with h5 extension')
```

To load to for later use

```
model = load_model('path of the h5 file which we saved using model.save')
```